# Converting a time duration format in excel

Tags: excel, time

I need to convert time intervals in excel. For example, I need to convert an entire column of time intervals from  13:01PM-13:15PM to 1:01PM-1:15PM. so on and so forth....Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Summary: Convert 13:01PM-13:15PM to 1:01PM-1:15PM

Comment: Is `13:01PM-13:15PM` all in a single cell?  Is it always that format?

Comment: Try `=TEXT(A2,"hh:mm:ss AM/PM")`

Comment: It seems it is text, is that right? If so, you will need to use text functions left, mid etc

Answer (score 1):

```
=TEXT(TIMEVALUE(LEFT(A1,FIND("-",A1)-3)),"h:mmAM/PM")&"-"&TEXT(TIMEVALUE(MID(A1,FIND("-",A1)+1,LEN(A1)-FIND("-",A1)-2)),"h:mmAM/PM")
```

Comment: Thanks! Habit, I guess. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data starts in A2, in B2 and copied down to suit:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"PM", ""),"AM", "")
```

then Copy ColumnB and Paste Special..., Values over the top and apply Text to Columns Fixed width with parsing either side of `-`.

In E2 and copied down to suit:

```
=TEXT(B2,"H:mmAM/PM")&"-"&TEXT(D2,"h:mmAM/PM")
```

though a shame to convert back to text time representations that have been converted to time values.

Copy ColumnE,Paste Special..., Values over the top and delete ColumnsB:D.

Example of output: `1:01PM-1:15PM`.

Answer (score -1):

=TEXT(TIMEVALUE(LEFT(A1,FIND("-",A1)-3)),"h:mmAM/PM")&"-"&TEXT(TIMEVALUE(MID(A1,FIND("-",A1)+1,LEN(A1)-FIND("-",A1)-2)),"h:mmAM/PM")
 this worked! thanks for the help!